# Measure of similarity using meronym/holonym edge on Wordnet

Tags: nlp, nltk, wordnet, word-sense-disambiguation

StackOverflow!

I searched on stack but I have not found any response about my doubt. My question is follow:

There are any measure of similarity for Wordnet which explores (navigate) holonym / meronym and hypernym / hyponym edges at the same time? I have found only measures which look for common hypernyms vertex on Wordnet ...

My question not contains a snippet of code, it's only about a Wordnet feature.

UPDATE:
I'm searching for a measure which not only use 'is-a' for find two concepts for semantic comparation. I want some measure which, in some cases, for "bind" two concepts admits "skip" 'is-a' taxonomy until reach most close hyperonym and choose navigate in 'member of'(holonyms/meronyms) taxonomy under some justificative.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail which/what features are you looking for? Note that WordNet is indexed by synset not lemma so you can only find relations (*-nym) through synsets and then generate the lemma.

Comment: Could you in code somehow type out the API that you're expecting for the feature? E.g. the input to the function, the desired output? Possibly link the input and output to an actual WordNet synset will help alot. http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn

Comment: Updated. Thanks, alvas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently read this paper: [Semantic Relatedness of Words and Phrases](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.05801)

Table 1 on p.3. shows how they used a weighting scheme. They then use the total weighted connections to decide if two words are related.

As far as I am aware, there is no ready-made function in nltk to do this.